# Hovering on one Value with class is affecting all the Values in the view Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of workSpaceResponse; let i = index">
<li>      
  <span (mouseenter)='checkList(item.value, i)' title='{{info}}'>
    <i [ngClass]="result ? 'fa fa-hourglass-end red' : 'fa fa-hourglass success'" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Pass
  </span>
</ul>
```

This is my Template, when I am hovering on one value , it is making same color, for all the list , dont know what i m doing wrong

```
result : boolean = false;
checkList(value){
    r = passingMarks - value
    if(r>1){
        this.result = true;
}
```

What I want is, if there are passed students then show thier value with green and those who are fail, show them with red.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question what's going on, but I think you are having the 'bubbling' effect.
So change to

```
  <span (mouseenter)='checkList($event,item.value, i)' title='{{info}}'>
```

and

```
checkList(event, value){
 event.stopPropagation();
 ....
 // as before
}
```

Comment: Does this help?